# Localhost ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: xampp, connection, localhost

I am having some problems with my xampp, or just localhost, ween i try to access to the localhost it says "page web inaccessible ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

I am using xampp, in windows 10, apache and mysql is on.

i saw, in other forum, that chrome is blocking the localhost url, so i instaled firefox and continues to not work.

*i tipe in cmd

```
hostname=barreto
```

so tried barreto/ in both chrome and firefox and the error connection keeps showing.

## here is the error.log from apache

```
[Tue Dec 01 20:00:00.027983 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 5708:tid 516] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name 
[Tue Dec 01 20:00:00.159553 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 5708:tid 516] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Dec 01 20:00:00.344435 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5708:tid 516] AH00455: Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.14 configured -- resuming normal operations [Tue Dec 01 20:00:00.344435 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5708:tid 516] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Oct 13 2015 10:54:13 
[Tue Dec 01 20:00:00.344435 2015] [core:notice] [pid 5708:tid 516] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Tue Dec 01 20:00:00.344435 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5708:tid 516] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 8324
[Tue Dec 01 20:00:00.866681 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 8324:tid 540] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Dec 01 20:00:01.027204 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 8324:tid 540] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Dec 01 20:00:01.074079 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8324:tid 540] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Tue Dec 01 20:24:29.888395 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 8076:tid 520] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Dec 01 20:24:29.945819 2015] [core:warn] [pid 8076:tid 520] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Tue Dec 01 20:24:30.015330 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 8076:tid 520] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Dec 01 20:24:30.046593 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8076:tid 520] AH00455: Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.14 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Dec 01 20:24:30.046593 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8076:tid 520] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Oct 13 2015 10:54:13
[Tue Dec 01 20:24:30.046593 2015] [core:notice] [pid 8076:tid 520] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Tue Dec 01 20:24:30.046593 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8076:tid 520] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 8932
[Tue Dec 01 20:24:30.531601 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 8932:tid 568] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Dec 01 20:24:30.663141 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 8932:tid 568] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Dec 01 20:24:30.694396 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8932:tid 568] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

I Need to know what happened or what can i do. thanks

Comment: The requests do not get through to your http server. Sounds like your http server simply is not listening to port 80 on the loopback interface. This could be because apparently you have configured ssl (why, on localhost?), so maybe you switched from port 80 to post 443 without realizing that.

Comment: BTW: chromium certainly does _not_ block access to localhost.

Comment: I suggest you turn off ssl / https, restat the http server and try again. Monitor the http servers access log file (not the error log file) to see if requests come through.

Comment: actualy it says in the apache, port(s) 85, 443;

Comment: Port 85? *85*? Why did you change it to 85? In that case you need to use`http://localhost:85/`. Doesn't make much sense in my eyes... I suggest you change it back to port 80, as that is standard for http and try with `http://localhost`.

Comment: i changed for listen 85 because of skype but the 443 i dont know
and i dont know what is the ssl / https 
right know in the apache access its nothing

Comment: I wish people would dump that stupid skype thing. Why does everyone want to get spied upon? But if you want to stay with port 85, then as wriiten above, try `http://localhost:85`.

Comment: i dont know what just happened but you helped already, i was using the 85 since the begining .... and somehow it stop working, now i tried localhost:85 and its running..

Comment: thanks bro, i live away from my family its good to get some image .. weel but its solved, and i wonder why from one day to another it stops access from the localhost .. anyway thanks !!

Comment: Access to `http://localhost` without a port number can never have worked if your server is listening on port 85. The browser will try to connect to port 80 if no port number is specified. No way around that.

Comment: btw i made a mutch clear question where i say that i change the port for 85 and someone closed the question .. you may answer the 2 if possible to answer a closed question i will accept the answers.. the other its
xampp localhost ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: i swear.. i was in port 85 using just localhost ..

Comment: Sorry, that cannot have worked. You must be confusing something.

Comment: And one question: do I get that right that you _knew_ that you have switched to port 85 and did not bother to mention that here?

Comment: i made a mutch clear question where i say that i change the port for 85 and someone closed the question .. you may answer the 2 if possible to answer a closed question i will accept the answers.. the other its xampp localhost ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: That is not an answer to my question. I am not interested in points or other questions. I would like to ask you to ask questions such that they contain all important information. Otherwise you waste the time of people investing to help others. That is not a nice thing to do. BTW: that is clearly explained in the posts about how to ask questions here. Please read those. Thanks!

Comment: i would apreciate you to check the other question, i made it one month ago, they say was not clear, it had the same it have here but MORE i apreciate that you check the other and understand WHY did i cut some stuff.. tried to make it simple.. its not easy after refuse my other question , i dont even know what was wrong with it!!! maybe some other guy didnt understant what you explain and just close the question , for me its miseducation.. but whatever sorry about that, and thanks for the answer..

Comment: I assume this is the question you refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33922206/xampp-localhost-err-connection-refused Two things I would like to point out here. Please don't get them wrong, I just try to explain things, so that you have less frustrating experiences in future: that question has very bad orthography, bad structure and readability. Whilst a spelling mistake is not an issue as such that question looks like you did not invest into making things easy to understand for people you ask for help. They gave up, that's all.

Comment: And another thing: this is a technical forum, targeting people who know what they are talking about. That is clearly explained in the meta posts about this page. _Read them_: questioners are expected to know what they are talking about. Changing a http servers listening port from standard 80 to 85 and then asking why a request without port cannot connect implies that you do _not_ really understand how network communication works. Such basics are something that can and should not be explained again and again in a question/answer style. That is what tutorials are for.

Comment: Apart from that: have fun, keep on learning, and have a great Sunday! :-)